# replace dot convention array to square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string that represent array:

```
context.something.1.nothing
```

The regex pattern would be: `\.\d+`.

How to replace it to the following format:

```
context.something[1].nothing
```

Of course the array can be any length.

Comment: can you edit your question so it apperas a little more clear?

Comment: No clue what the output/result is supposed to be....

Comment: @epascarello, sorry the result should be context.something[1].nothing

Comment: A useful tool for finding these solutions in the future: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could accomplish it in the following way ....

```js
var arr = 'context.something.1.nothing';
var newArr = arr.replace(/\.(\d+)/, '[$1]');
console.log(newArr);
```